# How do I switch a PIN diode using a TTL control signal?

Tags: rf, antenna, switching, ttl

I'm designing a transmit/receive switch for an antenna using a PIN diode.

The PIN diode I'm using is UM7512 make: Microsemi.

I need to switch between -400V (off) to +5V (on). The switching time should be 50usec.

On current  is 200mA.
Off current is 1-2 mA.

I need a reference circuit idea or design about this requirement.

How do I approach this design?

Comment: By first realizing how much capacitance you have to drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The schematic contains the PIN diode approx. DC model, there are no high frequency components on it.
The 2mA from the -400V can be set by R3.
[image: pindiodeoff]

The 200mA PIN diode forward current is set by R1.
[image: pindiodeon]

DC Transfer Characteristic:
[image: pindiodetrans]

The switching times are set by L1.
[image: pindiodetranzient]

If the 5V isn't enough to PIN diode forward current, the power supply voltage of U1 can be increased up to 18V. But afterwards you have to set R1 for the 200mA again.
The input voltage remains TTL and 5/3V CMOS compatible at every power supply voltage (U1).

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll try this one.

Comment: may I know the simulator you have used to simulate this.

Comment: I've used for this the simulator from TI ([TINA-TI](https://www.ti.com/tool/TINA-TI)).

Comment: Can I get your Tina file for this circuit so that I can simulate on my computer?

Comment: I would also like to know how did you get spice models for these components.

Comment: You can find the Tina files here in the [pin sw.zip](https://elektronikafoto.com/spice-models/) folder. Select the component with a left click and then right click to see the macro (component spice model).

Comment: Thank you for the link.